# Insert selected file to FileReader

Tags: java, swing

i want to take selected file in another class and insert it to other class in method `doit()` for variable `in` in `FileReader()`.
how can i insert in method doit(), in class Element,not this file "D:\Probe.txt",

```
public void doit() {
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Probe.txt"));
        out = new StreamResult("D:\\data.xml");
        initXML();
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            process(str);
        }
        in.close();
        closeXML();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Notably this file, that in `patch` variable from class Dialog, 
 `

```
if (cmd.equals("Quelldatei auswählen")) {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

    int ret = fileChooser.showDialog(this, "auswählen");
    if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

    File patch = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    contentPane.add(new JLabel("Quelldatei ist: " + patch));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem like you want the file in your doit() method without using the BufferedReader inside this method?

if im right, try this:

Save your file in a File Object and give this object as a parameter to your doit() method like:

```
public void doit(File file){
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but it must be readed with BufferedReader

Comment: oh..then try this: `public void doit(String path){in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));}`

Comment: are you understood so, that i want to assign a selected file in "patch" variable from Dialog class to FileReader in "in" variable from Element class